# How to add native android screen to flutter app?

Tags: android, performance, flutter, flutter-android

In my flutter application i need to implement simple native Android screen

(for example *handle back button pressed and create dialog - You are going to exit app (ok/cancel)*

or

*Button info about app* )

How can i do this in my flutter project?
**it shouldn't be flutter code**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Flutter's built-in function called WillPopScope and providing a dialog box with both options. Here's an example of the function.

```
  Future<bool> onBackPressed() {
   return showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => DialogueBox(
    title: 'EXIT',
    message: 'Do you really want to exit the App ?',
    onOKPress: () {
      SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
    },
  ),
);
```

}